# The dimensions for my ROC curve aren't correct

Tags: python, tf.keras

im really new to machine learning and was tasked with creating a ROC curve. I get the error ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [200, 400].
Here is a picture of my code for the ROC curve.

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
y_pred = basic_model.predict(X_test).ravel()
nn_fpr_keras, nn_tpr_keras, nn_thresholds_keras = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred)
auc_keras = auc(nn_fpr_keras, nn_tpr_keras)
plt.plot(nn_fpr_keras, nn_tpr_keras, marker='.', label='Neural Network (auc = %0.3f)' % auc_keras)
```

I actually know what the problem is I am using 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' for loss.(My advisor said I had to use it). Basically They also told me that now all I have to do is to change my X_test go from a 2D array to a 1D array. I have tried to use .flatten() but that didn't help? Any ideas on what I should do or any resources that I could study?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to set X_train=X_train[;,0]
Ravel() seems to not work.